# SQLDependency -- Invalid SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net, sqldependency

Best I can tell from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122%28SQL.105%29.aspx), I am not breaking any rules with this query, but the change event fires constantly with an invalid status.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT_BIG([PK_Column]) AS RecordCount 
FROM 
    [dbo].[My_Table] 
GROUP BY 
    Varchar_50_Column
```

If I do this, everything works correctly.

```
SELECT 
    [PK_Column]
FROM 
    [dbo].[My_Table]
```

However, I don't want to return this much data, and SqlDependency seems to require executing the query once after each time the change event fires to set up (or reset) the subscription.

Any idea what the flaw is in my first query?

Comment: Why aren't you using `COUNT_BIG(*)`? It's going to give the same answer, and I've never seen that syntax before...

Comment: Trying Count_Big(*).  Curious what syntax you've not seen before?

Comment: I've never seen anyone use `COUNT_BIG(column_name)`. I'm not saying it's invalid, but perhaps SqlDependency doesn't understand what it is.

Comment: I've never used COUNT_BIG, but for a period of time (long ago) started using COUNT(PK_Column) after I was incorrectly told never to use "*", even with COUNT.  I think the documentation that talks about valid aggregates is worded in a way that's open to interpretation.  I only did it this way (including the GROUP BY, which I don't need) because of how I interpreted the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [**special considerations on query notifications**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewzkxxh.aspx) If you make use of a group by clause you will  have to use `COUNT_BIG(*)`. On [**social.msdn**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlservicebroker/thread/29f41a3e-85f6-4296-8c81-5b5907b5b2c2) I found another user having a similar / same problem - solving it with this statement.

Comment: COUNT_BIG(/*) works (without GROUP BY!).  I believe the documentation on this is poorly worded, as even re-reading it now I still feel like it says GROUP BY is required and "/*" is not permitted.  Anyway, thanks for your answer and I have it working.