# Invalid query for SQLDependency

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sqldependency

The following query works fine with [SQLDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (e.g., as passed to [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033362/sqldependency-service-broker)):

```
SELECT SomeColumn 
FROM dbo.SomeTable 
WHERE Col1 = 'Foo' 
  AND Col2 = 'Bar'
```

Unfortunately, it appears that ExecuteNonQuery fetches all the matching rows to the client, even though it only returns an integer.  The above query returns far too much data, so I need to reduce the number of matching rows. To that end, I changed the above to the following:

```
SELECT SomeColumn 
FROM dbo.SomeTable 
WHERE Col1 = 'Foo' 
  AND Col2 = 'Bar' 
  AND DateTimeUtc >= '2013-12-01 12:00:00'
```

(Note that the column DateTimeUtc is of type DateTime2.)

However, this doesn't work: the SqlDependency OnChange handler is immediately called with SqlNotificationEventArgs having properties Info=Invalid, Source=Statement, and Type=Subscribe.

I'm aware there are [restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181122.aspx) on what such a query may be, but as far as I can tell, the above doesn't violate any of these?  Unless DateTime2 somehow qualifies as a 'double/real' for the restriction "The statement must not have comparison or expression based on double/real data types"?

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't answer why the query was invalid, I've found a different query that works and doesn't return a lot of data to the client.  As suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479473/sqldependency-invalid-sql), you can use COUNT_BIG(*) *without* a GROUP_BY, even though the documentation linked above suggests otherwise!  That is, the following works:

```
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) FROM dbo.SomeTable WHERE Col1 = 'Foo' AND Col2 = 'Bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be because you used DateTimeUtc in the where clause.